# Two different activities in a single activity

Tags: android, binding, android-activity

I am having one different requirement. I have an audio activity playing, in that I also have a map button that starts map activity. But what is to be taken care is the audio should be keep playing even when I am in map activity.

Can any body let me know the solution for this? I am breaking my head from days on this.

Thanks in advance,

Tejaswi

Answer (score 0):

Your Audio should be played by a service in the background.No matter you are roaming in many activities.Your audio will be playing as it is

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate this? I mean can you show me some lines of code snippet?

Comment: Thank you, I will go through this

Comment: I doubt about this method, because in this approach I will not have control on audio and here am not just playing audio instead I have array of images which are keep changing dynamically

Comment: why no control,you can start,stop service whenever you needed.You can also call method of a service directly